# jquery result not loaded into pdf when using dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm developing a reporting application and i use `dompdf` for create pdf report.
I want to load chart to the pdf result, but it have no result. but when i view in browser it show my expected result, but when i save to pdf it didn't loaded the chart..
this is my function created

```
function pdf_create($html, $filename, $paper, $orientation, $stream=TRUE)
        {
            require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
            spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');

            $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
            $dompdf->set_paper($paper,$orientation);
            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            if ($stream) {
            $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
            } else {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->helper("file");
            write_file($filename, $dompdf->output());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying your HTML content relies on jQuery? If so dompdf won't work for you. There are few server-based PDF rendering classes that support browser-oriented JavaScript. Your best bet is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Comment: @BrianS Actually I have success to load all content of a web page using dompdf, but i have 1 page that using jquery to show the graphics. I just have problem for this page.

Comment: dompdf can handle all standard HTML, but not anything related to browser JavaScript (jQuery included). If there's a way to capture the graphic from the web browser and in image format then you could send that back to the server. Otherwise you'll have to look for another PDF library or another graphics library (a PHP-based one would work).

Comment: @BrianS, or maybe it will be easier if i just print out the page right.,?

Comment: That's always an option if it meets your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Use MPDF. It is very good for creating Pdf file  from html content.

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Comment: mPDF does not support browser-oriented JavaScript. Few server-based PDF generating classes do.